# It gives error on Future<UploadTaskSnapshot> can anyone help me out

Tags: flutter

I m not able to solve this can anyone help me it gives "The name 'UploadTaskSnapshot' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument." on  and "The getter 'future' isn't defined for the class 'StorageUploadTask'." on .future at return line.

```
Future<UploadTaskSnapshot> _uploadPicture(BuildContext context, String path) async {

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    final File file = File(path);

    final StorageReference ref = _firebaseStorage.ref().child('${user.uid}/${path.split('/').last}');

    String eventData = selectedEvent is int
    ? null
    : ((selectedEvent is DocumentSnapshot) ? (selectedEvent as DocumentSnapshot).documentID : null);

    return ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg', customMetadata: {'event': eventData})).future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ref.putFile` returns a `StorageUploadTask` which handles the asynchronous file upload. Looking on the documentation as seen [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageUploadTask-class.html) - you could return the `onComplete` property which is a `Future<StorageTaskSnapshot>`.

`UploadTaskSnapshot` seems to be a class from earlier Firebase versions.